# canvas showing scene written by three.js gets out of the div

Tags: canvas, three.js

I intend to put a canvas inside a div and the canvas show scene written in three.js. The CSS uses Bootstrap. My colleague deals with the canvas and three.js.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <ul>
            <p id="Descriptiontext"></p>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
        <canvas id="canvas1" class="embed-responsive-item"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I run the page, the canvas somehow jumps out of the div and the structure shows like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <ul>
            <p id="Descriptiontext"></p>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
        ::before    
    </div>
</div>
<canvas id="canvas1" class="embed-responsive-item"></canvas>
```

If I replace canvas with iframe, it works fine as expected.

**Updated:**
I locate the statement that matters

```
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
scene = new THREE.Scene();    
scene.background = new THREE.Color("rgb(127, 128, 129)");//rgb(229, 229, 229)
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 700, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, .1, 10000);
camera.position.x = 10;
camera.position.y = 5;
camera.position.z = 10;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();    
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvas1, antialias: true });
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );    
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight-300);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

**Solved:**
I comment the statement `document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)`,  and it works.

Comment: Show us the javascript that creates and inserts the three.js renderer

Comment: You haven't shown the relevant code, but I'm guessing you're doing `document.body.appendChild()`, when you should be appending the child into the specific `<div>` that you want.

Comment: @Marquizzo Thank you for your advice. I comment the document.body.appendChild() and it works.